# Парсинг и вычисление мат. выражений

Tags: java

Есть выражения типа:

```
(x+7)^2*20(x^5+(x+7))*x
```

Нужно раскрыть скобки.
Каким методом оптимальней её парсить и потом вычислять? Рекурсивным спуском, сортировочной станцией или ещё каким?

Comment: И так, и эдак можно. И ещё каким-нибудь тоже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это учебное задание или что? Если что-то из реального проекта, то, по хорошему, вместо написания велосипеда надо взять что-нибудь готовое. На C# я бы сделал из этой строки класс на C# после чего передал компилятору... Наверняка в Java можно сделать так же.

Если надо больше скорости - можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь скриптовым языком, вроде [javascript](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) или [lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations).

Если надо построить AST, чтобы потом с ним сделать что-нибудь кроме вычисления - то можно использовать генератор парсеров вроде [javacc](https://javacc.java.net/).

Наверняка есть и библиотеки, специализирующиеся именно на разборе арифметических выражений. Но я о них не знаю.

---

Если же требуется наибольшая скорость работы в ущерб расширяемости и даже скорости разработки - то алгоритм сортировочной станции лучший (при аккуратной реализации).

Comment: Наверное не очень хорошо отвечать на вопрос по Java в стиле "На C# я делаю так, а на Java не знаю как .." и "библиотеки есть, но не знаю какие.. " . Мы же помним, что ответ должен содержать законченное РЕШЕНИЕ, а не предположения и сомнения.

Comment: Это и есть решение. Точнее, целых варианта 4 решения.

Comment: Тестовое задание, нужно java или python, на python я никогда не писал, поэтому java. Сортировочной станцией я распарсил, раскрыть скобки тем же алгоритмом не сложно. Мне важно знать что этот метод оптимальный или есть другие алгоритмы лучше

Comment: @user190370, Зависит от того, что подразумевать под оптимальностью. Если скорость выполнения - то сортировочная станция самая лучшая. Если скорость написания кода с возможностью расширения в будущем - то то что я написал.

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем есть такая замечательная штука как **Обратная польская запись**. Ссылка на [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) Еще хорошо описывают [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/100869/).

Comment: А получить-то эту замечательную запись как? :)

Comment: Обычно ее получают алгоритмом сортировочной станции, который автором вопроса был упомянут...